# Laravel 5.4: custom Middleware not working in route

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3, laravel-middleware

I created the following Middleware to check user session

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Checkusersession
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->session()->has('admin_name')) {
            // user value cannot be found in session
            return redirect('adminlogin');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

this is my route:

```
 Route::get('webadmin',['middleware' => 'usersession','Admin_controller@index']);
```

this is my kernel.php

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'usersession' => \App\Http\Middleware\Checkusersession::class,
];
```

this is my controller method that creates session:

```
public function auth_admin(Request $request)
{
    $admin_emai = $request->input('admin_email');
    $admin_password = $request->input('admin_password');

    $checklogin = DB::table('admin_login')
        ->select('admin_id','admin_email','admin_name')
        ->where([
            'admin_email' => $admin_email,
            'admin_password' => $admin_password
        ])->first();

    if (count($checklogin) > 0) {
        $request->session()->put('admin_id',$checklogin->admin_id);
        $request->session()->put('admin_name',$checklogin->admin_name);
        $request->session()->put('admin_email',$checklogin->admin_email);

        return redirect()->action('Admin_controller@webadmin');
    } else {
        return redirect()->action('Admin_controller@admin_login_page')->with('status','Incorrect Email ID or Password');
    }
}
```

I want the Middleware to check if the session (admin_name) exists or not. If not, redirect the user to the login page. but it is not working. if I access the webadmin (dashboard) directly from url, it gives me access even if the session is not set. Please help.

Comment: try making a dd($request->session()) before the redirect in your controller, to see if the session I successfully created, also check the config/session.php file to see if your configuration is correct. I´d recommend  using the Auth class of laravel.

Comment: Having the same problem here :/

Answer (score 3):

Your route is wrong, you should write it as (in L5.4):

```
Route::get('webadmin', 'Admin_controller@index')->middleware('usersession');
```

Or even:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('webadmin', 'Admin_controller@index');
});
```

In L5.3 (as you have tagged the question), and in L5.4 I guess you could also write:

```
Route::get('webadmin',['middleware' => 'usersession', 'uses => 'Admin_controller@index']);
```

Also, have you tried just to do a `dd(request());` or similar in your middleware-handle function to see that it is actually fired?

Comment: Having the same problem here. Route don't reach my custom middleware.